# Blue screen when using 8GB of RAM

Tags: windows, memory, crash, bsod

I bought 8GB (4 2GB DDR2 modules) of RAM from crucial.com. When I installed all 4 of them I get a blue screen of death about a minute after logging into Windows. If I take out one module and boot with 6GB things work fine. If I use a different 2GB module I had before I get the blue screen again. If I use a 1GB module (7GB total) then things are fine again.

Obviously something is wrong related to the memory, but I don't understated what. I've run a few different memory tests and all have come back clean. The problem appears when I have 8GB installed.

I've run

- memtest.exe
- Windows Memory Diagnostic

Windows Memory Diagnostic even passed when all 8GB were installed. I've run these tests several times and with different configurations of what modules are installed. I've lost track of how many passes now.

### The Memory

The new memory is two 4GB kits (2GBx2) DDR2 PC2-6400 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.8V 256Meg x 64.
http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/m3a76-cm/CT939195

### The Blue Screen

The error code is not constant. Plus there is something strange that is causing part of the message to get cut off to the left of my monitor so I can't read the whole code anyway.

It does always create a memory dump though. I've analyzed the memory dumps with WinDBG and there isn't a pattern to what's causing the crashes.

### My system

- Windows 2008 R2 Standard.
- AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+, 2200 Mhz
- Motherboard is Ausus M3A76-CM.
- No expansion slots are in use.

### Update

I've been able to use all 8GB after I changed the frequency of the RAM in my BIOS from auto to 333 (the second highest option). The highest option is 400 and doesn't work. The specs say the speed is 800MHz. So I don't understand why this has been an issue.

This is what CPU-Z shows now.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBocF.png]

The DRAM Frequency keeps moving from around 200 to around 300.

Comment: can you give us a detailed info of  MoBo, CPU and Memory?.

Comment: Which blue screen error / code do you get?

Comment: Updated. Motherboard is Ausus M3A76-CM. No expansion slots are in use. BSOD error code is not constant.

Comment: What are the specs of the memory you tried to install?

Comment: Two 4GB kits (2GBx2) DDR2 PC2-6400 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.8V 256Meg x 64

Comment: What happens when you use all 8GB and set the memory timings manually (not auto)? Possibly try with slower timings

Comment: post pictures of CPU-Z: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html Maybe the RAM timings are wrong

Comment: it it works with the lower speed, simple use it.

Answer (score 0):

some hardware devices map themselves into address space that they should not i.e. your video card may map its memory into your 7-8GB range, which will conflict with the OS -- your video card is trying to use the address space that the physical memory is using.

Comment: How does he determine if that is actually the case?  If that is the case after he determines it is the case, how does he resolve the problem, this explains the BSOD but does not explain how to precisely solve it.

Comment: Would not explain how changing the ram speed fixes the problem